# HTML image links not working on iOS

Tags: html, ios, image, hyperlink, touchscreen

I have a few "a href" image links and hovers on a website for navigation  ([www.byrdnick.com](http://www.byrdnick.com), in the non-mobile version of the site). It seems that these image links confuses iOS browsers. When you tap the image link once, it changes to the hover image. When you tap the hover image, nothing happens. When you tap the hover image a second time, you are finally redirected to the link.

Is there any way I can make these image links work or am I going to have to try a whole new method like a map or something?

Thanks in advance to all you gurus who help guys like me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of all the strange stuff your `psd2css.js` javascript does to tweak your divs and links.

I never used this tool, but it seems that your Web page was generated using an tool called psd2cssonline? This tool seems to add some obscure treatments behind the scenes to all your `<a href>` links. This is easy to see in the `psd2css.js` file, once the document is loaded, the script adds some magic to all your `<img>` `hover` functions.

I didn't study the whole javascript added by this tool, but I'm pretty sure that it is the reason of the problems. This tools does not seem to be compatible with touch-screen devices or somehow does mess with touch events in a mobile environment where "hover" are non-sense (you can't "hover" an item on a touch-screen!), and will probably need to be updated to be able to manage mobile versions of the web sites it generates.

Meanwhile, you may try to disable this script (and everything else that may be generated by this tool to automatically add behavior to your links) when your website is accessed on mobile, to avoid messing with the "hover" events in such cases and simply keep the standard behavior that you have without any similar script.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I am new to js, which is why I used psd2cssonline. I will try to isolate the script and make adjustments. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: I ended up just redesigning my website, which meant getting rid of that javascript. The problem seems to be solved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's something similar to what I have below and you don't have any odd class that is conflicting, you should be ok.

```
<a href="some link"><img src="some image" /></a>
```

Comment: For one button, and it's hover, it looks like this:  

      <div id="Layer-39" class="index link"  >
        <a href="http://www.byrdnick.com"><img src="http://www.byrdnick.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Blog-link.png" width="145" height="108" alt="index" class="pngimg" border="0" /></a></div>

      <div id="Layer-38" class="index linkover"  >
        <a href="http://www.byrdnick.com"><img src="http://www.byrdnick.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Blog-Hover.png" width="145" height="108" alt="index" class="pngimg" border="0" /></a></div>

Thank you for your reply!